# How to click on a hyperlink (aspx page) and save

Tags: vba, excel, automation, click

The hyperlink i'm trying to click using VBA looks like:

```
 a id=SearchResults_dgResults__ctl5_lnkbtnGetImage 
class=ItemStyle style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial" href="javascript:__doPostBack
('SearchResults$dgResults$_ctl5$lnkbtnGetImage','')">OH - House Bill of Lading /a
```

I already got the VBA code to take a numerical value from cell A1 from excel sheet 1 to prefill a search box, click the search button, and list several hyperlinks.  I need the 2nd part of the code to click on a particular hyperlink titled "OH - House Bill of Lading" (above).  I don't know if its because this is an aspx page but i've tried googling and using other codes but to no avail.

The code i have so far is:

```
Public Sub IE_Search_and_Extract()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument


    URL = "http://eglsiis12c.egl.corp/docvisionsearch/DocVisionSearch.aspx"

    Set IE = Get_IE_Window(URL)
    If IE Is Nothing Then
        Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    End If

    With IE
        SetForegroundWindow .hwnd
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState  READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend


        .Document.getElementById("House1_txtHouseBillNum").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        .Document.getElementById("House1:btnHouseSearch").Click


        While .Busy Or .ReadyState  READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend

End With
Call Uppercase
End Sub


Sub Uppercase()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set IE = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each IE In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(IE.innerText, "OH - Bill Lading of Lading") > 0 Then IE.Click
Next






End Sub
```

I tried doing it as 2 separate macros hence the call uppercase.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried `If InStr(IE.innerText, "OH - Bill Lading of Lading") > 0 Then IE.href`

Comment: Yes just tried it, still gives me an error

Comment: What is the error you get? Or just nothing happens when you run the macro.

Comment: Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With Block variable note set

and if i erase the 2nd macro, the first macro works fine with just putting in a number in the website and hitting the search.  But i don't see what object there is, and i'm not using any "with" commands in the 2nd macro.

Comment: You should read  [Passing Variables By Reference And By Value](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx).

Comment: Could you provide more of the HTML? I am also concerned about the appearance of what I assume to be <a> tags but are missing angle brackets.

Comment: @QHarr unfortunately this question was so long ago at a previous job i don't remember.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries. But thank you for getting back to me. I appreciate that.